# How to raise click event of a client side `reset ` button from code behind in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to raise click event of

```
<input type="reset" id="btnreset" class="ButtonText"/>
```

using (in code behind):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>alert('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + "'); document.getElementById('btnreset').click();</script>", false);
```

**EDIT:**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>function myFunction() { alert('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + "'); document.getElementById('btnreset').click(); }</script>", false);
```

There are no errors in console. But it doesn't work......

Comment: @MairajAhmad yes i see the alert

Comment: Try using document.getElementById('formID').reset()

Comment: You will have different form id if it is runat="server", so use ClientID

Comment: @Adil its not a serverside control. It is a html reset element. The Id remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are trying to reset form that is not set (changed) yet.**

You are resetting form on page load that wont have any effect as reset will reset the form values to the one that you have when page is loaded.

To see the effect of reset you should change the control the form control values first and then reset the form.

You probably need to initialize the value e.g. setting the all textboxes to blank etc.

You can better understand with this example.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x3xq9yhd/3/)

```
<form id="frm">
    <input value="123" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="myfun();" />
</form>    

document.getElementById('frm').reset();
alert("resetting form wont make the textbox empty on load");
function myfun(){
  document.getElementById('frm').reset();
}
```

Here we are reset form on load with no effect but if we change the value in textbox and reset the form using button the initial value of textbox will be restored.

To initialize value of inputs you can do something like

```
$('input:text').val('');
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

If you want to initial the form to the state that is at the first load then you can use [Response.Redirect](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fa8wa7sdt%2528v%3Dvs.110%2529.aspx&ei=zNJaVevNDIHzUrCjgagG&usg=AFQjCNE-0Xr16sqoZVS5ouOFXd91cv0Xnw&bvm=bv.93564037,d.bGQ) on the postback. It will initialize the form controls with minimum effort. You can use some session to show some message when page loads after redirect e.g showing that previous record saved successfully. You should not redirect in case of failure.

Comment: If i have to manually set each textbox value to blank, it kinda beats the purpose. I was thinking that this might be an easy way to reset form to blank.

Comment: That is how reset works... you can do that with jquery with little effort as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Where do I initialize textboxes with `$('input:text').val('');`?  On my aspx or code behind in script manager?

Comment: On either side, but doing it through RegisterStartupScript require more effort, if you want to do on post back then you will probably need to do it with RegisterStartupScript other wise you can do it in document.ready

Answer (score 0):

This is because your script is possibly executing before document loads,

Try,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>function myFunction() { alert('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + "'); document.getElementById('btnreset').click(); }</script>", false);
```

And call this function when documents loads like,

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Or you can do it in JavaScript code too,

```
window.onload="myFunction()";
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: I do not want to reset the form whenever there is a postback. I want to reset it only when certain condition is met.  How can I include `window.onload="myFunction()";` in the example I gave (`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`)

Comment: @Arbaaz look in your browser output console window. Probably there is an error with ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() . Did you do a view-->source and checked if the script is rendered?

Comment: You can write`window.onload="myFunction()";` just after function ends, and use `return false;` in the function if you dont want resetting.

Comment: Like this `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>function myFunction() { alert('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + "'); document.getElementById('btnreset').click(); return false; } window.onload="myFunction()";</script>", false);`.

Comment: Now, if resetting the form is all you need then use `document.getElementById('frm').reset();` somethng like mentioned by **@Adil**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function YorFnName(str) {
        alert(str);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="reset" runat="server" id="btnreset" class="ButtonText" />
</div>
</form>
```

cs file like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //whatever you want to pass , write it in yourfnname as a parameter
    btnreset.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return YorFnName('test')");
}
```